# How to identify the protocol of the Meteor connection

Tags: meteor, protocols, ddp

I've wondered how to identify the current protocol if it's using websocket or polling.

-- in the client. (appended for certainty)

I've found a valid information from the debug console.

`Meteor.connection._stream.socket.protocol`

and it seems to have one value among...

```
['websocket',
'xdr-streaming',
'xhr-streaming',
'iframe-eventsource',
'iframe-htmlfile',
'xdr-polling',
'xhr-polling',
'iframe-xhr-polling',
'jsonp-polling'];
```

is there more grace way to identify the current protocol?
and when would it be the fastest timing to detect the protocol?

By the way, I need it to use a different DDP server when the sticky sessions needed since AWS ELB doesn't support sticky sessions and websocket at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor uses DDP protocol. To connect to a different Meteor server and call its methods, use DDP.connect as follows.

```
import { DDP } from 'meteor/ddp-client'
DDP.connect(url)
```

Unfortunately, there is no graceful to get the protocol. onConnection returns an object which has some info.

```
Meteor.onConnection(obj => 
  { console.log(obj.httpHeaders.x-forwarded-proto); });
```

This returns 'ws' for websocket. This way of getting the protocol is not graceful!

Comment: maybe my question was wrong. I wanted to know the SockJS connection's protocol. among ['websocket',
'xdr-streaming',
'xhr-streaming',
'iframe-eventsource',
'iframe-htmlfile',
'xdr-polling',
'xhr-polling',
'iframe-xhr-polling',
'jsonp-polling'];

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.status()` gives a reactive data source.
(https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect)

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const stat = Meteor.status();
    if (stat.status === 'connected') {
      console.log(Meteor.connection._stream.socket.protocol);
    }
  });
}
```

something like that will give the current protocol in the client side.